# Tornado on_message blocking

Tags: python, tornado, blocking

I have a handler that has an expensive operation in it's on_message. The commented out lines are the different things I have tried. Can someone confirm the best practice when simply wanting to put an expensive task onto a back task?
This background task eventually replies to the clients via a call to IOLoop.instance().add_callback() which appears to be the recommended way.

```
     class PublisherRequestHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):

           executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

           def on_message(self, publishRequest):
               #self.queue.put(publishRequest)
               #IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.on_message_publish, publishRequest)
               #yield tornado.gen.Task(self.on_message_publish, publishRequest)
               yield PublisherRequestHandler.executor.submit(self.on_message_publish, publishRequest)

           @gen.coroutine
           def on_message_publish(self, publishRequest):
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I use it like this:

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.concurrent import run_on_executor

executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) 
class PublisherRequestHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
       @gen.coroutine
       def on_message(self, publishRequest):
           yield self.on_message_publish(publishRequest)

       @run_on_executor
       def on_message_publish(self, publishRequest):
           pass
```